# index out of range exception after creation of instance and initializing

Tags: c#

I am getting an error in my c# program. The error that I am getting is  Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

At this line of code

```
captiveViewSeriesData.data[0].Low = CapitalViewGraphData[0];
```

While debugging I can see that `captiveViewSeriesData.data` is `null` but I am re-Initializing it.

Do I need to convert the Data as an array? Could somebody tell me what the problem is?

```
public class SeriesGeneric<T> where T : class
{
    public List<T> Data { get; set; }
}

[TsType]
public class Data
{
    public decimal Low { get; set; }
    public decimal Q1 { get; set; }
    public decimal Median { get; set; }
    public decimal Q3 { get; set; }
    public decimal High { get; set; }
}

[TsType]
public class BoxPlotSeries
{
    public string color { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public List<Data> data { get; set; }
}

public SeriesGeneric<BoxPlotSeries> ChartSeries
{
    get
    {
        BoxPlotSeries captiveViewSeriesData = null;
        if (CapitalViewGraphData != null && CapitalViewGraphData.Length >= 5)
        {
            captiveViewSeriesData = new BoxPlotSeries();
            captiveViewSeriesData.color = "#FFB81C";
            captiveViewSeriesData.name = "Captive";
            captiveViewSeriesData.data = new List<Data>();
            captiveViewSeriesData.data[0].Low = CapitalViewGraphData[0];
            captiveViewSeriesData.data[0].Q1 = CapitalViewGraphData[1];
            captiveViewSeriesData.data[0].Median = CapitalViewGraphData[2];
            captiveViewSeriesData.data[0].Q3 = CapitalViewGraphData[3];
            captiveViewSeriesData.data[0].High = CapitalViewGraphData[4];
        }

        //ParentView
        BoxPlotSeries parentViewSeriesData = null;
        if (ParentViewGraphData != null && ParentViewGraphData.Length >= 5)
        {
            parentViewSeriesData = new BoxPlotSeries();
            parentViewSeriesData.color = "#C111A0";
            parentViewSeriesData.name = "Parent Company";
            parentViewSeriesData.data = new List<Data>();
            parentViewSeriesData.data[0].Low = CapitalViewGraphData[0];
            parentViewSeriesData.data[0].Q1 = CapitalViewGraphData[1];
            parentViewSeriesData.data[0].Median = CapitalViewGraphData[2];
            parentViewSeriesData.data[0].Q3 = CapitalViewGraphData[3];
            parentViewSeriesData.data[0].High = CapitalViewGraphData[4];
        }                               

        return new SeriesGeneric<BoxPlotSeries>
        {
            Data = new List<BoxPlotSeries> { captiveViewSeriesData, parentViewSeriesData }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: What you mean - _" but i am newing it up"_?

Comment: `new List<Data>()` creates an empty list.  So data[0] is always going to bomb.  Use the Add() method.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to access a specific index of a list that is empty. You need to add a new item instead. For example:

```
captiveViewSeriesData = new BoxPlotSeries();
captiveViewSeriesData.color = "#FFB81C";
captiveViewSeriesData.name = "Captive";

var data = new Data
{
    Low = CapitalViewGraphData[0],
    Q1 = CapitalViewGraphData[1],
    Median = CapitalViewGraphData[2],
    Q3 = CapitalViewGraphData[3],
    High = CapitalViewGraphData[4]
};

captiveViewSeriesData.data = new List<Data>();
captiveViewSeriesData.data.Add(data);
```

Comment: Getting error at the following line
 captiveViewSeriesData.data.Add(data);

Cannot convert from Systems.Collections.Generic.List<CoreAnalytics.Captives.Models.Data> to  CoreAnalytics.Captives.Models.Data

Comment: Sorry, that was my fault. Was going to write the code in a different way then changed my mind to make it more obvious for you. Try the update.